# Define variable in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

I am trying to mention varaibel in AWK. I try a few I used to use earlier, but can't figureout where I am doing wrong...

```
cat tld.csv
co.uk
com
```

code

```
while read -r ip 
do

awk -v i="$ip" -F, '$1 ~ /i$/ {print $0}' full-database.csv > tld-specific-database/$ip.csv


done < tld.csv
```

cat full-database.csv

```
a.com,bbb
co.uk,ddd
a.comi,bbb
c.ukip,ddd
```

Expected result

```
cat co.uk.csv
    co.uk,ddd

cat com.csv
    a.com,bbb
```

what i am getting now is

```
cat co.uk.csv
    a.comi,bbb

cat com.csv
    a.comi,bbb
```

Comment: `$1 ~ /i$/ ` will match a pattern ending in `i`, Also you don't need both shell loop and `awk` either one can do the job, but `awk` will be more faster than a shell loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to match is the value of variable i, not the actual character (or string) i:

```
awk -F, -v i="$ip" '$1 ~ i "$"' db.csv >$ip.csv
```

or slightly terser include the $ in the variable value

```
awk -F, -v i="$ip$" '$1 ~ i' db.csv >$ip.csv
```

(either way the default action is `print $0` so you can leave that out).

But you can do this in one pass *almost* as https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin says, *if* the number of patterns in `tld.csv` is reasonably small as you show, and this is more efficient if `fulldb.csv` is large (which you don't show, but 'full' suggests):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{x[$0];next} { for(i in x) if($1 ~ i "$") print > i ".csv" }' tld.csv fulldb.csv
```

or if you don't like the `NR==FNR` trick

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{while((getline<"tld.csv")>0) x[$0]} { for(i in x) ... }' fulldb.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in `awk` quite trivially just by redirecting to `$1` with `".csv"` appended to the end. It can be as short as:

```bash
awk -F, '{ print > $1".csv" }' full-database.csv
```

The only `awk` knowledge needed is that you need to quote the `".csv"` so it is treated as a string and concatenated with `$1`.

**Output**

Running the short script on your `full-database.csv` input file will produce the following output files:

```
a.com.csv
a.comi.csv
c.ukip.csv
co.uk.csv
```

(if `comi` is a typo -- let me know)

The contents of the output files are:

```
$ cat a.com.csv
a.com,bbb
```

```
$ cat a.comi.csv
a.comi,bbb
```

```
$ cat c.ukip.csv
c.ukip,ddd
```

```
$ cat co.uk.csv
co.uk,ddd
```

Look things over and let me know if that is what you were looking for, or if I misunderstood your question. I'm happy to help further.

---

**Using BOTH tld.csv (for tld names) and full-database.csv for input**

I thought again about your issue and it seems you want to use both files and check if the original `tld.csv` name matches, but if it doesn't, you need to `split()` the name on `"."` and try again with the last part. Putting that altogether, you would have:

```bash
awk -F, '
  NR == FNR {                         # fill a array with tld
    a[$1] = $1
    next
  }
  {                                   ## Process full-database.csv
    if ($1 in a)                      # is $1 already in a?
      print > $1 ".csv"               # output into csv if so
    else {                            # otherwise
      split ($1, tld, ".")            # split $1 into tld array
      if (tld[2] in a)                # check if last part in a
        print > a[tld[2]]".csv"       # if so, print into csv
    }
  }
' tld.csv full-database.csv
```

**Output**

Now you have only two output file:

```
$ l1 *.csv
co.uk.csv
com.csv
```

Which contain:

```
$ cat co.uk.csv
co.uk,ddd
```

and

```
$ cat com.csv
a.com,bbb
```

Both the interpretation of the question sounded reasonable -- I'll leave it to you to let me know if one, both or neither were on point.

Comment: But OP doesn't want to use entire $1 as the filename, only the part matching a value from the 'tld' file, and only if there is such a match. I propose an alternate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 -- yep, I thought about another interpretation using both files and wrote that answer up too. One has to be close to what he was looking for. It was confusing not knowing if the data files were a small sample and full-sample or both needed to be incorporated (I think that is the better reading after considering it a bit longer)